# MVC large amount of editable data - how to prevent calling db on each postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

So I have this view and partial view with gridview(using DevExpress) in it. This view saves large amount of data which is editable. On each Edit button click in the gridview postback is performed and partialview action is executed. My data load is performed in this partial view action, so everytime a row is edited data is called from db and is passed to `return PartialView(model)`. So for big amount of data this slows the operation. Is there a way in MVC data to be called from db just on page load (initial view) and to be preserved between postbacks (edit button clicked on each row)

Comment: Load your `GridView` with `Ajax` on client side

Comment: Can you provide [mcve] where the operation becomes slower? DevExpress' GridView already has paging feature to optimize data load, how many data passed into that?

Comment: Use ajax to post only the data for the row your editing and then update the DOM using javascript/jquery. There is no need to return all the html again

Comment: Your implementation approach is not correct in this case. If you have partial views and you just need to update/save the partial view data then you have to make ajax call rather than postback until it is not necessary. Your view form postback automatically executed when you click on edit button this is the issue not an issue with DevExpress controls

Comment: My postback is not on clicking Update button and saving updated values, the postback is on clicking EditButton and showing edit form where users is alowed to edit the item. This is my scenario showed in devexpress: https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/EditModes